Setting xy position of Popen object and closing object
I can open the OSK keyboard for windows in Python using Popen but cannot set the xy position or close it on event. I have tried to set the xy position of it adapting the answer from this:
``
Changing the position of the console window with Python (Windows)
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
The following is the code I used -  I was expecting the position to be set when the keyboard is called. Also I expected the osk keyboard to be closed using the .terminate() command when called.
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import win32gui

appname = 'osk'
xpos = 50
ypos = 400
width = 800
length = 600

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if appname in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, xpos, ypos, width, length, True)

def openKeyboard(event):
    global pro
    pro = subprocess.Popen("osk", stdout= subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    time.sleep(10)
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)

def closeKeyboard(event):
    pro.terminate()


This really has nothing to do with popen. Popen doesn't know what a window is, and that it has a position. And which process may have some, unknown to it, stuff called "windowr". This may be a win32gui question. I wouldn't know for sure, since I know nothing of windows myself. But I would start by checking if at least you capture the windows. And if not, if you would, if you add a consequent sleep between spawning of process (Popen) and the enumeration of windows to find the one that belong to osk (at least, I surmise this is what this EnumWindows thing does:

it enumerates all currently displayed windows, to find for one that have osk in its title, and move it). Because, if this enumeration is done in milliseconds, chance are that osk hadn't yet the opportunity to open its window when the enumeration is done.

Also, please provide the real code. The one you posted is quite good for a first question (quite rare are first askers who post real [mre], with everything needed, but nothing more, to illustrate the problem). But still, it is clearly not the real one (you use subprocess module that you never imported, since you imported only Popen from it. If that is the only problem, it is easily fixed, of course. But it is never reassuring to have a proof that you didn't really executed yourself the code of your question, and make me wonder if some other difference could explain your problem)

But in the meantime, my first hypothesis is (if that is really how it is in real code) that the window simply doesn't exist soon enough to be found by the enumeration. Try to add a time.sleep(30) just after Popen. If 30 seconds later, your window moves, that would confirm my intuition. If it doesn't, that would prove that there is another problem (not necessarily that my intuition is false, but at least that it dosn't explain alone the problem). You could also try to open an 'osk' window before lauching this code.

In other words, try to separate the different aspect of your program: running the window (Popen) can be separated from the rest, by lauching it manually yourself, before you run the program. Likewise, you could avoid any question about whether the events detection that trigger the move works, by having a python program that does one thing only: straight away start moving any "osk" windows it can find. Then, if that works, it will be time to try to make it the result of the callback of an event, and then, to try to have that same code run "osk" itself.

Thanks chrslg. I have updated the question to reflect that I was using the correct imports. I have tried your suggestions but to no avail.
